# Ubuntu ISO Structure

Tags: filesystem, iso, uck, personalization, squashfs

I am working on an ubuntu iso personalization script based on the buggy [uck](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uck/) ..
The uck team seemed to know what they were doing, they used the structure of the ubuntu iso image a lot ..

The problem is, There are several files I can't understand, like: ISO/casper/filesystem.squashfs , and rootfs .. These files seem to be really important for customizing the environment.

That said, I need a brief explanation of the structure of linux iso images in general, and ubuntu iso in specific. Thanks ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of answering myself isn't appealing, but I'm writing this for the sake of others who viewed this question hoping they'd get an answer.

After googling, I found some interesting pages discussing the topic ..

- [RootFS](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bootdisk-HOWTO/buildroot.html) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rootfs)
- [SquashFS](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/SquashFS-HOWTO/) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squashfs)
- [Initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initramfs) , and [the old initrd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initrd)
- [the mysterious isolinux](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolinux)

And for Live CDs specifically ..

- [Linux Live CDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCD?action=show&redirect=LiveCd)
- [Linux Live CD Customization](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch)